# AD620 in Proteus: timestep too small

Tags: sensor, simulation, temperature, instrumentation-amplifier, proteus

I've made this circuit in Proteus, as a part of a practice report:

[image: LM35 temperature sensor connected to an AD620 instrumentation amplifier, measuring output voltage of the latter]

In real life it works, as I built and tested it. But in Proteus, when I want to run the simulation, I get these errors:

```
[SPICE] transient GMIN stepping at time=3.41026e-006
[SPICE] TRAN:  Timestep too small; timestep = 1.25e-019: trouble with instance d:u1:3.
```

I realized the error disappears when the gain of the amplifier is 1: that is, when I remove the resistor R1 (letting it be "infinite"). Otherwise, it won't work.

Why do I have this error, and how can I solve it?

### **UPDATE # 1**

As @Andyaka pointed out, I tried with very small (as Proteus complained about 0 Ohm) resistance values. The circuit I got is this one:

[image: The same circuit as the first one, with 1p Ohm resistors in the AD620 inputs and the reference pin]

But when I run the simulation, I get other errors :(

```
[SPICE] Gmin step [45 of 120] failed: GMIN=4.21697e-007
[SPICE] Gmin stepping failed
[SPICE] Source step [12 of 120] failed: source factor =  10.0000
[SPICE] Too many iterations without convergence.
```

### **UPDATE # 2**

I tried the procedure @berto said in the answers section. I connected a load resistor of \$10k\Omega\$ to \$V_{\text{out}}\$ and the ground, and then connected the voltmeter in parallel with it, but I got these errors:

```
[SPICE] transient GMIN stepping at time=2.14996e-007
[SPICE] TRAN:  Timestep too small; timestep = 1.25e-019: trouble with node #b:u1:e3#branch.
```

Two interesting facts when I played with the circuit at this stage:

1. When I disconnect the voltmeter and put a load resistor of \$0 \Omega\$ (thus, a connected wire from \$V_{\text{out}}\$ to the ground), the simulation starts and continues with *no errors*.
2. When I disconnect the voltmeter but leave the proposed load resistor (\$10k\Omega\$) from \$V_{\text{out}}\$ to the ground, the simulation stops with the same `timestep too small` error.

Comment: Try putting zero ohm resistors in series with each input and pin 5. Sometimes this works with obstinate models. Same problem in other sims too.

Comment: @Andyaka I can't! The program complains that "Value must be positive!" :( I'll try with a very small resistance, though.

Answer (score 10):

Try this.
System --> Set Animation Options --> SPICE Options
Change "Default Settings" into "Settings for Better Convergence" and load it.

Comment: Had same problem ... this suggestion worked

Comment: Wow...  Its worked... had the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a load resistor. An open circuit (ideal voltmeter) at the output can generate simulation problems. Something bigger or equal to \$ 10 k\Omega\$ should do it.
Also try adding 100kΩ resistors between the inputs and ground, so the currents will have a return path.

Comment: I did it but the errors appeared again. One interesting fact is when I disconnect the voltmeter and just put a cable between \$V_{\text{out}}\$ and the ground, I get _no errors_.

Comment: what signal are you using in Vout?

Comment: I saw something in the datasheet, try adding \$100 k\Omega\$ resistors between the inputs and ground, so the currents will have a return path.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Speaking about the first question, it is direct current. And for the second, let me try it! :)

Comment: :( It hasn't worked yet. I see now why the \$100k\Omega\$ resistors, but SPICE still complains!

Comment: ...another thing you can try is adding small capacitors. Also increase a little the 1 p\$\Omega\$ resistors, because small time constants can create fast oscillations, 1 m\$\Omega\$ is a more realistic value.